# Laravel: multi-language, display a word in two languages together in the same <div>

Tags: laravel-5.5

I have a list of words translated in a few languages in json files in lang folder. How can I get, for instance, both the French and Spanish translated strings together in a  ?

Comment: `{{app()->setLocale('fr')}}
        <h1>@lang('messages.welcome')</h1>
        {{app()->setLocale('en')}}
        <h1>@lang('messages.welcome')</h1>`

Comment: Above a concept that might help.